# Pathfinder: Wrath of the Righteous Auzmezar's age at the fall of the Stonewilds 4621AR

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-settings

I'm creating an elf druid for the wrath of the righteous campaign. I thought it would be fun to have him be old enough to remember when the worldwound formed and when the druids of the Stonewilds became siabraes. In particular I'm having him encounter the druids in the mid 4590s and since that was 30 years before the actual fall of the stone wilds, I wasn't sure whether he should be meeting Auzmezar as a child (meaning he would have been in his 40s at the fall of the stone wilds) or whether Auzmezar was already a young adult when my character meets him (making him an old man at the fall of the stonewilds). Can anyone shed some light on this subject?

note: I am not necessarily looking for an exact age (although that would be great) just anything that would let me know the stage of life Auzmezar was in during this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auzmezar was the leader of the druids of the Stonewilds when they fell. Furthermore as a druid20/hierophant5 he has [Timeless Body](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Timeless-Body-Ex-), and thus may not be changed in aspect much from one time to another during a normal human lifespan - and with [A Thousand Faces](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-A-Thousand-Faces-Su-), that gets even more sketchy. Also, [reincarnate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate) resets age, so can be used to live effectively forever (though druids might object to this as a perversion of the life-death cycle). Was Auzmezar on his first incarnation at the time? Maybe... As ruler of a bunch of druids it seems a bit more 50/50 though.

So the short answer is "ask your GM/make up whatever you want."